# DataGridViewImageColumn doesn't display an image

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, dataset

I'm trying to display an image on a cell of a DataGridViewImageColumn that is filled from data from a DataSet. For some unknown reason, it doesn't seem to show the image.

```
 DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        //adding image column
        imageCol.Name = "pic";
        ItemsDataGridView.Columns.Add(imageCol);
        imageCol.Width = 145;

        ItemsDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["pic"].Value = Image.FromFile(@"../../Resources/Items/1.jpg");
```

and i checked the path, it's correct.

any thoughts?

Comment: What showed in the cell? Empty cell or default bitmap?

Comment: A red X with a white frame?